# Developing a Real-time Multiplayer Game in Android

Tags: android

I am facing problem in signing in using the google real time muleiplayer api's even after following all steps throughly as given in the documentation. Following is the link from where I have referred: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init.
I am not getting any error but my `main activity extends BaseGameActivity` when i start my game it calls `onSignInFailed()` automatically but i am calling the `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()` method from `BaseGameActivity` which is used for initialization of sign in on the button click none of the overridden methods gets called not even `onSignInFailed()` nor `onConnectionFailed()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal for it to call `onSignInFailed` on startup if have never signed in before. That's working as intended. Then, you should call `beginUserInitiatedSignIn` when your button is clicked, and then either `onSignInFailed` on `onSignInSucceeded` should be called.

I'd suggest putting some print statements around your code and `BaseGameActivity` to figure out what methods are being called to figure out what's happening.

By the way, the most common cause for sign-in errors is having a Client ID that's incorrectly set up. I'd recommend taking a look at the troubleshooting guide to see if there is a problem with your setup:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for the help i have resolved my issue without extending the BaseGameActivity the exact problem was that the GameClient was not getting initialized properly So after wasting my so many days i got one solution a day before from the link http://goldenhammersoftware.blogspot.in/2013/05/google-play-game-services-for-android.html  This was very helpful link for me now i have sucessfull in implementing multiplayer

Comment: Is there a compulsion to everytime sign the apk for testing even if we make some changes ? because its wasting my time very much on keeping signing it every time i make some changes in the code.